# Comparing two thresholds in two different groups in r

Tags: r

I've got this data (I am limited to 30000 characters, so it is better this way):
`https://justpaste.it/9psbt`

I wanted to check from which point the slope started to be significantly different in each group (`CHD` and `sains`) according the new variable `VE/VO2`:
Package needed:

```
library(readxl)
library(emmeans)
library(sjstats)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(MuMIn)
library(ggplot2)
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
library(splines)
library(reghelper)
library(tidyverse)
```

So `CHD` first:

```
#filter data
#keep CHD
dfCHD<-dftest %>% 
  filter(group == "CHD")

dfCHD<-dfCHD %>% 
  filter(temps == "1")

dfCHD$VE_VO2<-dfCHD$VE/dfCHD$absVO2 ##create new variable for the DV


####knot point i.e. line change at 50% power
point1chd<-lmer(dfCHD$VE_VO2 ~bs(dfCHD$percent_absVO2, knots = c(50), degree = 1)+(1|id),data = dfCHD)
summary(point1chd) # this is not that important its just the model showing the sig of the two slopes
```

Then using different threshold, I found that 78% was the one for the CHD group, according this code, since the output mentions that the lower AIC is at 78%:

```
###78%
point3chd<-lmer(dfCHD$VE_VO2 ~bs(dfCHD$percent_absVO2, knots = c(78), degree = 1)+(1|id),data = dfCHD)
summary(point3chd)
anova(point1chd, point3chd)
```

Then, same for `sains`:

```
#keep healthy
dfsains<-dftest %>% 
  filter(group == "Sains")

dfsains$VE_VO2<-dfsains$VE/dfsains$absVO2 ##create new variable for the DV

####knot point i.e. line change at 50% power
point1sains<-lmer(dfsains$VE_VO2 ~bs(dfsains$percent_power, knots = c(50), degree = 1)+(1|id),data = dfsains)
summary(point1sains) # this is not that important its just the model showing the sig of the two slopes

###59%
point4sains<-lmer(dfsains$VE_VO2 ~bs(dfsains$percent_power, knots = c(59), degree = 1)+(1|id),data = dfsains)
summary(point4sains)
anova(point4sains, point1sains) # compare fits, use the AIC (no p value produce because no df)
```

I've been able to get this plot representing `VO2` in function of `percentage power` according group `CHD` and `Sains`.

[image]

Here the code for the plot:

```
dftest%>% 
  filter(percent_power < 100) %>% 
  mutate(power_group = case_when(
    group == "CHD" & percent_power >= 78 ~ "CHD - Power >= 82",
    group == "CHD" & percent_power < 78 ~ "CHD - Power < 82",
    group == "Sains" & percent_power >= 59 ~ "Sains - Power >= 60",
    group == "Sains" & percent_power < 59 ~ "Sains - Power < 60"
  )) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = percent_power, y = relVO2, col = power_group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x) +
  xlab("Percentage of power (%)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("V", O[2]," (mL/min/kg)")))
```

So my question here is: how do I statistically compare the threshold between the `CHD` and the `sains` groups ? We only have the `78` and `59` thresholds at the moment. I need the mean, SD and p-value for the comparison.

I have simply tried to compare the two threshold with `anova` but because it is not the same group (`CHD` vs `sains`), I was not able to perform it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think this can be done without incorporating your method for determining the breakpoints into a model where those are estimated. I am also confused by your plot, which indicates not just changes in slope, but changes in intercept as well.

Comment: Dear Russ, I thought I put it the code already for determining the breakpoints into a model. The original idea was to determine from which point the slope started to be significantly different. Then I found from`78` and `59` % in `CHD` and `Sains`, respectively. Moreover, the intercept is different, because I split the line into 2 different for each group, according again, the significant change of the slope. Does it make sense ? Thank you

Comment: It seems to me you got these results by inspection. There needs to be an explicit model that relates the parameter estimators to the data, including how the two datasets are related.

Comment: You are right, the % have been found by inspection: I have tried different % to find the one with the lowest AIC. That is how I got `78` and `59`. Do you have another method which will ultimately give us the possibility to compare the two thresholds ? thank you!